# Check which signal is the calller of the signal

Tags: qt, signals-slots

Is there any way to know whether `inst1` or `inst2` was the trigger for the slot in the next code?

```
MyClass inst1 ,inst2;

connect (inst1, sigInst1(), this, mySlot());
connect (inst2, sigInst2(), this, mySlot());


void mySlot(){
   // here I want to know if inst1 or inst2 got me into this slot.

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just call `sender()` and you get the pointer of the object emitting the signal.

Entry for `QObject * QObject::sender() const [protected]` in documentation is [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qobject.html#sender).